# Statistical significance tests for contingency tables in panel survey

Tags: statistical-significance, panel-data, contingency-tables

I'm having a bit of trouble choosing what statistical test to pick. Hopefully you can advise.

I have a panel survey in two waves (with almost all the same respondents retained from wave 1 to wave 2. I measure respondent's party identity in the first wave and their response to another question in both waves (a categorical variable). I've constructed contingency tables where I look at the change in proportion of respondents in each category of that second question, from wave 1 to wave 2, by their party identity in wave 1.

I was wondering what would be the best way to check the statistical significance of these changes. Ideally I want to be able to say what the significance of each cell in the table is.

Thanks in advance!